# Texts in bubbles overlap in force simulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, bubble-chart

I have a script in which I am using force simulation for both bubbles and texts over the bubbles. For some data where bubbles are nearby to each other, texts are getting overlapped. I have used forceCollide in simulation, so why do texts still overlap?
Image for an instance of my dataset is given below:

[image]

My script is as given below:

```
//var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50}

    var margin = 40,
    width = 600,
    height = 400;

    var xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return +d.student_percentile;
        })])
        .nice() 
        .range([0, width]);

    var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                return +d.rank;
            })])
            .nice()
            .range([height, 0]);

    var svg = d3.select('.chart')
        .classed("svg-container", true)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('class', 'chart')
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 680 490")
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
        .classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

    simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
            return xscale(+d.student_percentile);
        }))
        .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
            return yscale(+d.rank);
        }))
        .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(24)); 

    var local = d3.local();
    circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("opacity", 0.3)
      .attr("r", 20)
      .style("fill", function(d){
            if(+d.admit_probability <= 40){
                return "red";
            }
            else if(+d.admit_probability > 40 && +d.admit_probability <= 75){
                return "yellow";
            }
            else{
                return "green";
            }
      })
      .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
            local.set(this, d3.select(this).style("fill"));
            d3.select(this)
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .ease(d3.easeBounce)
              .attr("r", 32)
              .style("cursor", "pointer")
              .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
              var d = this.__data__;
              show_details(d);
        }
       )
      .on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", local.get(this));
            d3.select(this).transition()
              .style("opacity", 0.3)
              .attr("r", 20)
              .style("cursor", "default")
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .ease(d3.easeBounce);
            remove_details();
      });

    texts = svg.selectAll(null)
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.abbreviation;
      })
      .attr("pointer-events", "none")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "10px")
      .attr("fill", "black");

    simulation.nodes(data).on("tick", function() {
        circles.attr("cx", function(d) {
                return d.x = Math.max(20, Math.min(width - 20, d.x));
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return d.y = Math.max(20, Math.min(height - 20, d.y));
            })
        texts.attr("x", function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return d.y;
            });
    });
```

I want all circles and texts to be non-overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(24));
```

You're assigning a radius of `24` to **all** texts, regardless their sizes. That's not correct. The radii should depend on the size of the texts.

Check my demo below. Here, I'm using `getComputedTextLength()` to get the length of the texts and setting a new property (`size`). Then, in the simulation, I use that property:

```
.force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.size
}))
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [{
  text: "some text"
}, {
  text: "a longer text here"
}, {
  text: "an even longer text here"
}, {
  text: "short text"
}, {
  text: "a long text"
}];
var texts = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.text
  });
texts.each(function(d) {
  d.size = this.getComputedTextLength() / 2
})
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(250, 150))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return d.size
  }))
  .on("tick", tick);

function tick() {
  texts.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.This is the fiddle I have after applying your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ngfoha56/11/
The problem is in this way my bubbles are getting overlapped and texts also still overlap in the real dataset and also some in the fiddle. The reason I had taken 24 in forceCollide was radius of my circles was 20, so I was thinking that maybe keeping 24 would keep them away but this doesn't really go well with texts.

Comment: First: there is no text overlapping in your fiddle, look again. Second: in your question, 24 won't work because some texts are bigger than the circles.

Comment: I understand that 24 won't work. So, based on your solution, I am now using Max(biggest_circle_radius, d.size) in forceCollide. In this way both my circles and texts are not overlapping(mostly). I am still finding some exceptions though!

Comment: Well, just wait for someone else posting another answer with a different solution. I can't help you more than this.